# AS2 for loop code no work

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

i have use for loop to control another clip

this is working

```
sub_btn1.onRelease=function(){ title1.gotoAndStop(1);}
```

so i try following code

```
for (var i=1; i<=9; i++) {this[ "sub_btn" + i ].onRelease=function(){
    this["title"+i].gotoAndStop(i); }}
```

but this["title"+i].gotoAndStop(i) not working!

anyone can help me to fix this problem?

thanks a lot!!

Comment: My AS2 is hazy, but if it's "onRelease.function()" in the working code, why change it to "onRelease=function()" in the for loop?

Comment: Sorry! "onRelease.function()" was wrong and i already revise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in understanding what `this` refers to.

Event handler which you function is refers to the target object of this event. So for
`sub_btn1.onRelease=function(){}` the `this` inside `{}` give you refer to the `sub_btn1`.
Obviously what your ["title"+i] doesn't situated in button you released. So change it to right object (if buttons situated where titles is it will be  `this._parent["title"+i].gotoAndStop(i);`);